# keeping <pre> text on the same line as <span> text

Tags: html, css

The following HTML should print the phrase `pass Test Case: Buzz::GetInfo( [struct BUZZINFO *] 0x1f84fa8c )` with some fancy formatting. But, it puts the `pass` on a separate line from the rest of the text. How can I get them to be on the same line such that the border of the `pass` blends with the border of the rest of the text?

Thanks,
PaulH

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>   
    <style type="text/css">
    pre
    {
        border-style: solid none;
        border-width: 1px medium;
        line-height: 120%;
        padding: 5px;
        color: #333333;
        background-color: #EEFFCC; 
        border-color: #98BF21;            
        overflow: auto;
    }

    .pass
    {
        background-color: #98BF21;
        #background-color: #AACC99;
        border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        display: block;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: 1px;
        outline: 1px solid #98BF21;
        padding: 3px 0 4px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        width: 80px;
        font-family: verdana,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
<div><span class="pass">pass</span><pre>Test Case: Buzz::GetInfo( [struct BUZZINFO *] 0x1f84fa8c )</pre></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<pre>` is a block-level element. You could try setting it to `display: inline-block`, or use some other tag, like `<code>` which also uses fixed-width fonts and whatnot to display text.

Comment: changing to `<code>` fixed it. If you put this in an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the .pass class, change `display:block` to `display:inline`.
Add `display:inline` to the CSS for pre.

Here is a [fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Wx2ku/)  it looks ugly because I selected and pasted out of your question directly into the fiddle without worrying about adding carriage returns.

Answer (score 1):

`pre` is block-level, you need to make it inline. Also, you need your "pass" to be inline as well :). Here's a working version: http://jsfiddle.net/secqA/

Answer (score 1):

`<pre>` puts the content on a new line by default. Instead, use `<code>`, which keeps the content on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display: block` from the styles for .pass

If you want to keep block styling like padding, margin, etc. use `display: inline-block` instead.

Comment: neither removing `display: block` nor changing it to `display: inline-block` fixed it. removing it just makes the `pass` look small and funny. changing to `inline-block` made no perceptible difference.